# Why can only one inner region of a plane be subdivided?

Tags: modeling

Starting from this situation:

[image]

Subdividing <kbd>W</kbd> the inner rectangle leads to the following model, please notice that the center points of the adjacent rectangles have been displaced. Subdividing other rectangles is no longer possible. 
To analyze the behaviour, I tried to subdivide the outer regions first this works flawless.

Why is that?

[image]

View from vertex mode:

[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/30973)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer faces are now ngons. When you try and subdivide the outer faces they *are* being subdivided, which you can see when going into vertex mode:

[image]

The subdivision can't happen like before because while the faces *appear* to be rectangles, the topology is no longer quad based.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the superfluous vertices in the middle of an edge. Only the ones needed for the ngons.

Comment: No, they're the result of subdividing the outer faces after subdividing the internal ones first. You were saying that it was not possible to subdivide the outer faces and I'm saying they were being subdivided even if it didn't look like it.